# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment when using division

Tags: pyspark, databricks, division

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment when using division.

Dividing two integer columns in a pyspark dataframe and receiving this error. Any ideas?

[image]

Reproducible:

```
simpleData = (((1, 2), (2, 6), (3, 6))
columns= ["sales","users"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df = df.withColumn("users", df["users"].cast(IntegerType()))
df = df.withColumn("sales", df["sales"].cast(IntegerType()))
df['buy_rate'] = df['sales']/ df['users']
```

Answer (score 1):

just small tweak .

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
simpleData=((1, 2), (2, 6), (3, 6))
columns= ["sales","users"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df = df.withColumn("users", df["users"].cast(IntegerType()))
df = df.withColumn("sales", df["sales"].cast(IntegerType()))

df1 = df\
    .withColumn("buy_rate", (F.col("sales") / F.col("users")))
display(df1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karthik, and very good approach with the assignment to the new column within the withColumn() this worked beautifully.